# Починить JSON для System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

Столкнулся с проблемой при переходе с NewtonJson на System.Text.Json
а именно с капризным восприятием JSON при десериализации:

1. Все наименования полей должны быть закавычены
2. Все кавычки полей и значений должны быть только двойными.

Всвязи с чем назрел вопрос, как это исправить поддержав обратную совместимость?
Я накидал код на коленке, но думаю есть более элегантное решение. Если кто подскажет, то буду безмерно благодарен.

пример, надо исправить следующие JSON `{id:444}` или `{'id':444}`, превратив их в `{"id":444}` ну, естественно если есть входящие поля, то исправить и их

Например надо починить следующий JSON

```
{
  'a' : '"2222 ' ,
  a2: true,
  "a3":null,
  b : { 
    "c": "' text \"{} []\"",
    'c2': '"othertext \'"'
  }, 
 "d":[ 'r', "tt"]
}
```

Код чинилки:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static string RepairJson(string json)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder(json.Length + json.Length / 10);
        var charValue = "1234567890truefalse.null";
        char quote = ' ';
        bool openQuote = false;
        bool readValue = false;
        bool readUnQuoteName = false;
        var lastChar = ' ';
        foreach (var c in json)
        {
            bool WriteQuote = false;

            if (readValue && !openQuote && char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            {
                continue;
            
            }

            if (lastChar != '\\' && (c == '\'' || c == '"'))
            {
                if (!openQuote)
                    quote = c;
                if (!openQuote || c == quote)
                {
                    WriteQuote = true;
                    openQuote = !openQuote;
                }
            }
            if (!openQuote && c == ':')
            {
                if (readUnQuoteName)
                {
                    result.Append("\"");
                    readUnQuoteName = false;
                }
                readValue = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!openQuote && readValue && !charValue.Contains(c))
                {
                    readValue = false;
                }
                if (!openQuote && !readValue && !readUnQuoteName)
                {
                    var cu = char.ToUpper(c);
                    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= '0' && c <= '9' || c == '_')
                    {
                        result.Append("\"");
                        readUnQuoteName = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!openQuote && readUnQuoteName && char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                {
                    result.Append("\"");
                    readUnQuoteName = false;
                }
                if (openQuote && lastChar != '\\' && quote == '\'' && c == '"')
                    result.Append('\\');
            }

            if (WriteQuote)
                result.Append('"');
            else
                result.Append(c);

            if (lastChar == '\\' && c == '\\')
                lastChar = ' ';
            else
                lastChar = c;
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }


}
```

Comment: Костыль вижу, а где остальной код? Модель данных, код сериализации, что получается, что должно получиться. То что вы написали, выглядит страшно и ненадежно, осталось понять, ради чего именно.

Comment: Какая разница что за модель?
сериализатор ругается на записи типа {id:"444"} или {'id':444}

Comment: Пример приведите.

Comment: Ок, так сериализуйте string, и будут вам кавычки

Comment: Читаете json с помощью Newtonsoft и тут же сохраняете. Готово, json починен!

Comment: Я избавляюсь от NewTon это и есть цель, а вы предлагаете его использовать )

Comment: Да, использовать его, если нужно починить имеющиеся файлы. После чего можно перейти на новый тул.

Comment: `{id:444}` или `{'id':444}` - откуда такое? Зачем это вообще надо поддерживать? Это по сути не JSON.

Comment: А если эти файлы приходят от другого поставщика, то нужно ему сообщить о некорректности данных, пусть чинит свой код.

Comment: Мы не просто так уходим от NewTon это задача поставлена руководством. Плюс сериализация - десеарилизация это лишнее время, а JSON иногда очень большие.

Comment: Ранее Ньютон справлялся с такими данными, уход с несовместимостью - это поднятие версии и гемор для потребителя. Если была бы задача сделать забив на потребителя, то сделали бы так.

Comment: Есть один вариант попробовать. Можете какой-нибудь сложный JSON, содержащий наибольшее разнообразие кейзов привести? Попробую поиграться. Ну и его исправленную версию.

Comment: Вообще таите кейзы решаются весьма просто. Создаете новую версию API, с другим префиксом, например `/v2/`, документируете ее и обязуете всех потребителей на нее переехать, скажем, за год. Через год старую отключаете, и готово.

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: Теперь понятно, поиграюсь чуть позже.

Comment: [Миграция](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0) действительно не всегда возможна напрямую. / Можно попробовать поискать другие библиотеки для работы с json. Их есть немало. Некоторые хвастают, что быстрее, чем System.Text.Json.

Comment: Да, я это читал. Вариант с починкой через Newton взлетел бы если бы от него не отказывались =((

Comment: Переход вообще ради чего затеян? Нужна более высокая производительность? / Можно пока сделать так: десериализуем с помощью System.Text.Json. Работает быстро, всё хорошо. Если вылетает исключение, тогда десериализуем с помощью Newtonsoft. Медленно, но работает.

Comment: Дело в том что Web.API это как мидлвейр регится, там либо так либо так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поковырялся, задача и так и сяк сводится к разбору JSON, так как исходя из его структуры, требуется определенная реакция на символ, а это делается [примерно так](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.cs). При этом в невалидном JSON нужно корректно разэскейпить строки.

Вот мой наколеночный вариант.

```
enum ExpectedToken
{
    Name,
    Value,
    Comma
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText("sample.json");
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var options = new JsonWriterOptions { Indented = true, Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping };
    using (var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(ms, options))
    {
        ExpectedToken state = ExpectedToken.Value;
        var wayBack = new Stack<JsonTokenType>();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            i = SkipWhiteSpace(text, i);
            if (i >= json.Length) break;
            if (state == ExpectedToken.Value)
            {
                switch (text[i])
                {
                    case '{':
                        writer.WriteStartObject();
                        wayBack.Push(JsonTokenType.StartObject);
                        state = ExpectedToken.Name;
                        break;
                    case '[':
                        writer.WriteStartArray();
                        wayBack.Push(JsonTokenType.StartArray);
                        break;
                    default:
                        i = ReadValue(text, i, out string value, out bool isString);
                        if (isString)
                            writer.WriteStringValue(value);
                        else
                            writer.WriteRawValue(value);
                        state = ExpectedToken.Comma;
                        break;
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (state == ExpectedToken.Name)
            {
                i = ReadPropertyName(text, i, out string name);
                writer.WritePropertyName(name);
                state = ExpectedToken.Value;
                continue;
            }
            if (state == ExpectedToken.Comma)
            {
                switch (text[i])
                {
                    case '}':
                        writer.WriteEndObject();
                        wayBack.Pop();
                        break;
                    case ']':
                        writer.WriteEndArray();
                        wayBack.Pop();
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        if (wayBack.Peek() == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
                            state = ExpectedToken.Name;
                        if (wayBack.Peek() == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
                            state = ExpectedToken.Value;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
}

private static int SkipWhiteSpace(string text, int index)
{
    while (index < text.Length &&  char.IsWhiteSpace(text[index]))
        index++;
    return index;
}

private static int ReadPropertyName(string text, int index, out string name)
{
    char quote = text[index] == '\'' || text[index] == '"' ? text[index] : '\0';
    int i = text.IndexOf(':', index + 1);
    name = text[index..i].TrimEnd();
    if (quote != '\0')
        name = name.Trim(quote);
    return i;
}

private static int ReadValue(string text, int index, out string value, out bool isString)
{
    char quote = text[index] == '\'' || text[index] == '"' ? text[index] : '\0';
    int i = index;
    if (quote != '\0')
    {
        i++;
        while (i < text.Length && text[i] != quote)
        {
            if (text[i] == '\\')
                i++;
            i++;
        }
        isString = true;
        value = Regex.Unescape(text[(index + 1)..i]);
    }
    else
    {
        while (i < text.Length && !char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i]) && text[i] != ',' && text[i] != '}' && text[i] != ']')
            i++;
        isString = false;
        value = text[index..i];
        i--;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Очень грубо, ничего не оптимизировал, но работает

Вывод в консоль

```json
{
  "a": "\"2222 ",
  "a2": true,
  "a3": null,
  "b": {
    "c": "' text \"{} []\"",
    "c2": "\"othertext '\""
  },
  "d": [
    "r",
    "tt"
  ]
}
```

От вашего отличается вывод в поле `c2`, у вас лишний `\`. На гениальность не претендую. Чтобы убрать отступы пробелами, просто уберите `Indented = true`.

В качестве оптимизации, можно на спаны переписать, а выход писать не в строку, а в поток. Чисто теоретически можно и на входе от строк избавиться, тогда получится вообще быстро, но я сильно этот вариант не обдумывал.

Comment: Интересный подход, попробую протестить на скорость. Для нас она очень важна. Спасибо. Действительно у меня лишний слэш выводится

Comment: Так же у себя добавил в Ваш код проверку на выход за границы, например если в конце есть пара пробелов

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик ну вы этот код не на вход в API ставьте, а на подхват в случае исключения при десереализации, на вторую попытку. Тогда производительность этого кода не будет такой критичной. Ведь большинство запросов должны быть изначально валидные.

Comment: Вы не против если я внесу изменения в Ваш код?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик вносите конечно.